# How to stop a method until I get the response in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server, nio

I have written a simple TCP Server program that receives data from the client. My main() method looks like this:

```
Acceptor acceptor = Acceptor.open(new InetSocketAddress(port));
Session session = acceptor.accept(); //accepts connection from client and returns session object
FIXSession transport = session.getTransport();
String str = transport.receive(); // receives data from client

doWork(str); // do the remaining process.
```

In the above code, I am trying to receive the data from client using "transport.receive()" method. If suppose client takes some time to send the data, meanwhile my main program is going to the next step "doWork(str);" and the result is null. How can I make the main() thread to wait until I receive data from the Client. In future I may run the doWork(str) method in other thread. So I need to make the doWork(str) thread to wait until I get the data from the Client. Is there any way to do?

Comment: You need to provide more information about your code. What's the code for receive method?

Comment: If you are using the API I am looking at "project: Philadelphia" transport.receive returns the number of bytes. Looks like you need to setup a message listener.

Comment: Yes, I am using Philadelphia. Even though it returns the number of bytes, if the bytes received less than 0 then it has to wait until the received bytes are greater than 0. But it is simply jumping to the next step. I want it to wait until the client sends the data to the server. That is the number of bytes received should be greater than zero.

Comment: actually the receive function returns str only. I modified the source code to return a string. I haven't checked your process in my code. I will do it tomorrow. Then I can vote for your answer. As of now, your answer is best suitable for me. Thank you

Comment: Well, at least the one I am looking at in [FIXSession](http://api.paritytrading.com/philadelphia/latest/com/paritytrading/philadelphia/FIXSession.html#receive--) does not this. This method returns an **int**, not a string. Maybe you should clarify your question and point to the exact version of that library you are using.

Comment: Ok I am sorry..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the OP:

> Even though it returns the number of bytes, if the bytes received less than 0 then it has to wait until the received bytes are greater than 0

So, the straight forward way to turn this into a blocking call:

```
int numBytes = transport.receive();
while (numBytes == 0) {
  Thread.sleep(SOME_TIME);
  numBytes = transport.receive();
}
```

for example. If you want code to wait; then write code that waits. But of course, that still doesn't answer how to *actually* receive a message. As the idea is that you need a `MessageListener` to actually receive messages.

Comment: Surely this API has blocking I/O already in it? Sleeping in network code is an abomination unto the Lord.